# Can MYSQL support databases with sizes around 4 GB? Will I have any performance issues?

Tags: mysql, performance

I am planning to have a database of size more than 12 million records all of them in a single table and no other joins etc, used for search, filtered based on field names of the table, approximately 4 GB size in MYSQL backend and php frontend.

Question is can MYSQL support databases with sizes around 4 GB, Will I have any performance issue when I do a search using php

Will I be able to get results in atleast 30 to a 60 Secs

your suggestions please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you will have performance issues.**  Every application has database performance issues, even with much smaller databases than yours.  You need to study and work to understand how to use the RDBMS technology to its best advantage.

The good news is that you can do it.  A database of 4GB is not excessive, and many success stories involve databases that are much larger.

I suggest you start by studying the following resources:

- [Chapter 7: Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html)
- [High Performance MySQL, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716) by Baron Schwartz and others.
- [MySQLPerformanceBlog.com](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) where the top MySQL performance consultants write.

Combining technology like the [APC cache](http://php.net/apc) or [Memcached](http://php.net/memcached) with PHP and MySQL is also practically required for high-performance PHP applications.  Because the fastest database query is the one you don't have to run (because the data is already in a cache).

We can't answer your question about getting query results in 30 to 60 seconds, because we don't know what type of queries you need to run.  There are many other factors for performance. The naive and general nature of your questions indicates that you have a lot of study to do before you will be successful.

Comment: If queries where simple select statements like, Select A,B,C From table where A='ASDF' AND B='444' AND C='666', Will that still take a lot of time ??

Comment: It shouldn't take more than 1 second if you use a covering index.  That's homework for you: to find out what a covering index is and how to create one.

Comment: You will NOT have performance issues if you can use indexes effectively for your queries.

Comment: @symcbean: My point is that every database application needs some analysis work to determine how to use indexes most effectively.

Answer (score 2):

There is no fundamental reason why a 4GB database with 12 million rows should have performance issues, but thats not to say it wont.  If you are doing basic select queries on a single table with reasonable indexes your results should return in a matter of seconds not 20 - 30 seconds.  Loading the result set (if it is large) into your page might take a considerable length of time.

Why not try it out? Can you load your data into a test server running MYSQL / MARIADB and do a few test queries, that would give you a good indication to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course mysql can support small databases such as 4G. You won't have performance issues, as your database server will have > 4G of ram, so the entire database can be kept in ram.

If you had wanted to use a large database, MySQL can of course support that as well, but you won't be able to keep say, 1Tb, in ram.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these links:

http://tag1consulting.com/MySQL_Engines_MyISAM_vs_InnoDB

http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/35641.html

MySQL works with two known DB engines, MyISAM and InnoDB. InnoDB is known for its high performance on large scale databases.

Comment: I'm not convinced that MySQL either MyISAM or InnoDB are well known for their "high performance on large scale database". MySQL lacks several performance optimisation features that (e.g.) Oracle has (hash joins; decent partitioning). InnoDB has also been shown to get rather slow on very large tables. However you're not going to get those problems much at 4G. Engines such as Infobright Tokutek and InfinitiDB attempt to work around these to use MySQL with very large data.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate indexes and simple queries will handle SELECT performance issues.

Comment: Not all simple queries can be performed fast - even with appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a point of reference, we have a 15GB database, but it's split among various tables. The largest tables have the simplest structures, that helps keep performance up.